# UiPath automation tool - Read pdf with OCR activity

Tags: c#, automation, ocr, text-extraction, uipath

I want to extract text from pdf in UiPath and save it to excel or text file to make text editable, but i find these problems if someone can help me:

1- When I use "Read pdf with MS Office OCR" activity and save the text to text file, it will be created but empty. Although it works only with Example.pdf file in this example:
http://www.uipath.com/kb-articles/extract-text-with-ocr

2- When i use Abby OCR and put the AppID with password -I have ABBYY FineReader trail version- an exception shown. 
message: a generic error occured in GDI+.
Source: Abbyy OCR
Exception Type: ExternalException

3- How can i add row to Data Table as string data

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUqPK.png)  an image for my workflow to extract pdf file.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using Citrix automation then there is already an activity is available "**Read pdf**" which will return the output with text.

Side notes - Depends on Pdf data if it is containing only text then it will return all and if it is a scanned image pdf and all then you should go with the read pdf ocr approach.